# Change data type from dbl to int for one column only

Tags: r, tidyverse

Assignment Task:
Need help to change the data type to integer format for the `n` column only.

Here is the code:

```
pizza %>%
  select(day,driver,free_wine)%>%
  group_by(day,driver)%>%
  summarise(n=sum(free_wine,na.rm=TRUE),.groups = 'drop')%>%
  arrange(desc(n))%>%
  head(1)%>%
  as.integer(n)
```

Note: current data format is dbl for `n` column - I can only use tidyverse library and prefer to use function `as.integer()`.

Code is not working - giving below error

```
Warning in pizza %>% select(day, driver, free_wine) %>% group_by(day, driver) %>%  :
  
NAs introduced by coercion
```

And gives this output:

```
[1] NA NA 20
```

The expected output should be in the below format

```
Day       Driver  n
<chr>     <chr>   <int>
Thursday  Rick    20
```

Comment: I believe you could just use `mutate(n = as.integer(n))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as written passes the entire dataframe to `as.integer()`. To instead apply it to just one column, you can add it to your `summarise()` call:

```
pizza %>%
  select(day,driver,free_wine)%>%
  group_by(day,driver)%>%
  summarise(n=as.integer(sum(free_wine,na.rm=TRUE)),.groups = 'drop')%>%
  arrange(desc(n))
```